# How to display header of column after identifying value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, header, xlrd

I'm analysing an excel spreadsheet and need to find the cell that contains the value that is closest to, but less than 500. I believe I have achieved this but then need to know the corresponding header name which I cannot work out how to do.

```
loc=("/Volumes/Project/Andes_Glacier_Inventory.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
headers = sheet.row(0)
print(sheet.row_values(1,3))

a = np.array(sheet.row_values(1,3))

value = 501
print (a[a<value].max())
```

Comment: you can check out pandas that might help. You may add a screenshot I may be able to solve it with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.argmax`:

```
headers[np.argmax(a * (a<value))]
```